# Argument 1 passed to Aws\Multipart\AbstractUploader::Aws\Multipart\{closure}() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2-advanced-app

I have a yii2 advanced project for uploading and downloading images. And I have used **ctala/yii2-aws-s3** for uploading/downloading to AWS s3 acccount. It is working fine in my local machine but it is not working in aws live server. I am getting the following error while uploading image to s3,

**Argument 1 passed to Aws\Multipart\AbstractUploader::Aws\Multipart{closure}() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /var/www/html/Exc/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php on line 203**

```
$imageName = '0fyuh_vidv7notmdnb-fzn4oqlylpqho_italy-hd-wallpapers-22.jpg';
$fileName = Yii::$app->params['uploadedImagePath'].$imageName;  
$response = Yii::$app->get('s3bucket')->multipartUpload(
                    "uploaded_images/$imageName",
                    $fileName,
                    $concurrency,
                    $minPartSize
                );
```

Is there any solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTTP requests sent concurrently in the AWS SDK for PHP are done so using a single thread in which non-blocking calls are used to transfer one or more HTTP requests while reacting to state changes (e.g., fulfilling or rejecting promises).

Check out this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html

Comment: I didn't get this point. Can you please explain this a little more?

Answer (score 2):

I see nobody answered this. After 5 hours of debugging i found solution to this problem. Some of extensions for php are missing here. I had problem here migrating from php7 debian jessie to CentOS, since CentOS doesn't have some extensions preinstalled i had this error.

My problem was that i was missing simplexml for php7. This is really hard to debug since aws-swk expects instance of Exception but guzzle is passing instance of Error object.

What you should do is to go to `Aws\Multipare\AbstractUploadManager` class to LINE 132 and change `otherwise(function (\Exception $e)` to
`otherwise(function ($e)` and there you should see your real error.